# enable http strict transport security for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, https

I have `Spring Boot` application running on server. All requests are done via HTTPS.

I need to enable Strict Transport Security. I my `Spring Boot` configuration I enabled

```
.http
....
.headers()
    .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
    .includeSubDomains(true)
    .maxAgeInSeconds(HSTS_MAX_AGE_365_DAYS);
```

And also added annotation `@EnableWebSecurity` to the configurer class.

But still, no requests contain `strict-transport-security` header and also in `security` tab (in firefox) it is mentioned that transport security is disabled.

[image]

What is the problem? Why it is not enabled?

Comment: It should be enabled by default, if you're making the request over SSL.

Comment: Probably should...But as you can see, it is not.

Comment: @11thdimension it seems it returns header when I configure spring boot application to use https in properties

Comment: @lapots can you share the fix? i have the same issue